# Records in PureScript

Tags: records, type-kinds, purescript

I don't quite understand why this works:

```
module Records where

type Element e = { element :: String, label :: String | e }
type Sel = ( value :: Number, values :: [Number] )

type Select = Element Sel
```

while this says `Cannot unify # * with *`.

```
module Records where

type Element e = { element :: String, label :: String | e }
type Sel = { value :: Number, values :: [Number] }

type Select = Element Sel
```

(Note the '()' around the right hand side of Sel instead of the '{}'.)

I've read here https://leanpub.com/purescript/read#leanpub-auto-objects-and-rows that `forall r. { firstName :: String, lastName :: String | r }` desugars to
`forall r. Object (firstName :: String, lastName :: String | r)`

I'm still a bit confused, why you can't use the record-sugar for extending records.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `Object` *type constructor* is parameterized by a *row of types*. In kind notation, `Object` has *kind* `# * -> *`. That is, it takes a row of types to a type.

`( value :: Number, values :: [Number] )` denotes a *row of types* (something of kind `# *`), so it can be passed to `Object` to construct a type, namely

```
Object ( value :: Number, values :: [Number] )
```

Note that `{ ... }` is just syntactic sugar for the Object type constructor, so this is the same as

```
{ value :: Number, values :: [Number] }
```

Both have kind `*`, so it doesn't make sense to pass this thing as an argument to `Element`, since the type variable `e` in `Element` has kind `# *`.

Put another way, `Element Sel` in your second example unrolls to

```
{ element :: String, label :: String | { value :: Number, values :: [Number] } }
```

which desugars to

```
Object (element :: String, label :: String | Object (value :: Number, values :: [Number]) )
```

which fails to kind-check due to the thing of kind `*` in the tail of the outer row.

Comment: thank you very much. This explains everything :)
I think it would be really nice to have an entry about records in the wiki.
Like what the `{ value :: Number, values :: [Number] }` desugars into. And an example how you would extend a record would be really helpful.
Thanks again

Comment: No problem. Feel free to copy this onto the wiki if you like.